# NGINX not correctly reverse proxying web app requests to their relative location

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two web apps running on my home server, one on port 7001 and the other on port 3578.

Both of these apps have some REST API routes, that all start with `/api`.

My NGINX config is as follows for the two locations blocks:

```
location /deals/ {
    include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.65:7001/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
}

location /speed/ {
    include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.65:3578/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
}
```

This is the result of a whole afternoon of Googling and searching around...

`192.168.1.65` is the local network IP address of my home server.

**The problem** that I am facing is that when those web apps make api calls, they aren't making the calls relative to their (new proxied) locations, but rather from the domain url.

When I navigate to `https://my-domain.com/deals` and `https://my-domain.com/speed`, I can see my web apps respectively.

**BUT** the data is never loaded because they are both calling `my-domain.com/api` instead of `my-domain.com/deals/api` or `my-domain.com/speed/api`. I can see this in the network tab of Chrome dev tools, both return 404s.

When I navigate to `192.168.1.65:7001`, I can see my web apps and the data loaded correctly.

When I type in manually in the address bar `https://my-domain.com/speed/api/example`, I can see that it can answer correctly the GET request with a 200 status code.

How can I make them make the calls from their respective locations?

Comment: The problem is not in **NGINX**, but the web apps: they should perform API calls to the correct URL. They can either have a configurable base URL or create the correct URL based on the browser's `window.location` object.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, thank you for your reply!

I had thought about that, but I was convinced NGINX had a feature to alleviate that.

Comment: You can do simple substitutions of the content returned by the proxied server with the [ngx_http_sub_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html), but it probably won't work with JavaScript files. It's easier to refactor the apps detect the base URL of the API.